# Stripe status: 'requires_source', always

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments

I have a project about smartboards. When purchase successfully I want to do something, when purchase is not successfully I want to do another something. My querys doing well but the stripe's status always 'requires_source'

My codes below. Im using firebase database, function (nodejs) and Flutter.

```
`const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")("mykey");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config());


exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    var db = admin.firestore();

    try {
        let customerId;

        //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
        const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
            email: req.body.email,
            limit: 1
        });

        //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
        if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
            customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
        }
        else {
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.body.email
            });
            customerId = customer.data.id;
        }

        //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer
        const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
            { customer: customerId },
            { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' }
        );

        //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
            currency: req.body.currency,
            metadata:{
            userid: (req.body.userid),
            bookid: (req.body.bookid),
            bookimage: (req.body.bookimage),
            booklevel: (req.body.booklevel),
            bookname: (req.body.bookname),
            smartboard: (req.body.smartboard),
            purchaseurl: (req.body.purchaseurl),
            },
            customer: customerId,
            description: 'NATIONAL ENGLISH BOOK APP'
        })

        if(paymentIntent.status == 'succeeded'){

        var packetRef = await db.collection('highschool_preview_info').doc(req.body.bookid).get();
        let afterbookid = packetRef.data().bookid;
        let afterbookimage = packetRef.data().bookimage;
        let afterbooklevel = packetRef.data().booklevel;
        let afterbookname = packetRef.data().bookname;
        let aftersmartboard = packetRef.data().smartboard;
        let afterpurchaseurl = packetRef.data().purchaseurl;


        const satisdb = await db.collection('Person').doc(req.body.userid).collection('myBooks').doc(req.body.bookid).set({
        'bookid': afterbookid,
        'bookimage': afterbookimage,
        'booklevel': afterbooklevel,
        'bookname': afterbookname,
        'smartboard': aftersmartboard,
        'purchaseurl': afterpurchaseurl,
        })


        var myBooksSecondControl = await db.collection('Person').doc(req.body.userid).collection('myBooks');
        var denemeDelete = await db.collection('Person').doc(req.body.userid).collection('myBooks').doc('deneme');
        if(denemeDelete.exists){
        denemeDelete.delete;
        }else{
        console.log('great455');
        }

        res.status(200).send({
                    paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
                    ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
                    customer: customerId,
                    success: true,

                })
    }

    res.status(200).send({
                paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
                ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
                customer: customerId,
                success: false,

            })






    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(error.message)
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
});
```

this is my status parameter of firebase function link
[image]

but this is my status parameter of stripe event.

[image]

probably the function can not get the status parameter from stripe event but Im not sure I don't have much experience about stripe.

Front-end codes below.

```
Future<void> initPayment(
    {required String email,
      required String amount,
      required String userid,
      required String currency,
      required String bookid,
      required String bookimage,
      required String booklevel,
      required String bookname,
      required String smartboard,
      required String purchaseurl,
      required String client_secret,
      required BuildContext context}) async {
  try {
    // 1. Create a payment intent on the server
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            'myFunctionLink'),
        body: {
          'email': email,
          'amount': amount.toString(),
          'currency': currency,
          'bookid': bookid,
          'userid': userid,
          'bookimage': bookimage,
          'booklevel': booklevel,
          'bookname': bookname,
          'smartboard': smartboard,
          'purchaseurl': purchaseurl,
          'client_secret': client_secret,
          //userid & bookid ekle
        });

    final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
    log(jsonResponse.toString());
    // 2. Initialize the payment sheet
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonResponse['paymentIntent'],
          merchantDisplayName: 'National English',
          customerId: jsonResponse['customer'],
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonResponse['ephemeralKey'],
        ));
    await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Payment is successful'),
      ),
    );
  } catch (errorr) {
    if (errorr is StripeException) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('An error occured ${errorr.error.localizedMessage}'),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('An error occured $errorr'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the PaymentIntent is created successfully on your [Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments), it means the Stripe API call was successful (you can console.log paymentIntent, ephemeralKey and customerId to make sure they are fine).

You would need to debug further on your Firebase function *after the call the Stripe API*, the part of calling db.collection.

Comment: Im so sorry, I couldn't understand what you mean clearly. Should i check or fix to what?